# Exclude hidden system drives from Windows 8 file history backup?

Tags: windows-8, backup, windows-backup, file-history

I'm using Windows 8 file history and noticed that on my laptop, it's copying an extra drive's contents onto the backup share (the $OF drive). My laptop has a 8gb SSD, so I'm assuming it's this data, perhaps? How can I exclude this data from the backup, as there are about 3000 folders it's creating (and growing).

[image: Win 8 file history]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it by navigating to `Control Panel` > `File History`. Click on the `Clean up versions`(see image below).

[image]

[image]

Comment: These aren't old files, though. These are just a ton of files on a caching SSD drive.